# performance surprises with browserify

Tags: javascript, performance, browserify, bundling-and-minification

I'm migrating my build process from a list of concatenated scripts to Browserify.

#### Old version

- All vendor scripts from Bower
- build: concatenate all scripts and minify (uglifyjs) the results

#### New version

- As much as possible, use `npm` modules
- when not available, fetch them from `Bower` and use `debowerify`
- build: `browserify` (and +`watchify`) bundle, then minify (`uglifyjs`) the results

What surprised me:

- my reload time with `watchify` is about 3s, is that not a lot?
- the final script is **3 times bigger** than with the previous builds, whereas the modules are the same. ***Erratum : not true, see below***

Do you think something is wrong with my build?

---

### EDIT

There is no increase of script size. I did not measure it correctly, because what I saw of the old version was the gzipped size. I'm leaving it here so people figure it out more quickly if they get fooled in a similar way.

The problem of bundling time still remains.

---

I'm using Gulp, here is the relevant part of my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

var browserify = require('browserify'); // bundles CommonJS modules (require('...')) into a file for the browser.
var watchify = require('watchify'); // fast watch for browserify
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'); // for creating sourcemaps
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify'); // for JS minification
var jade = require('gulp-jade'); // for Jade compilation


function scriptsBundle(watchified){
  var b = browserify({
    entries: ['./src/frontend/app.js'],
    debug: true,
    transforms: [
      //bNgAnnotate
    ]
  });
  if(watchified){
    b = watchify(b);
  }
  b.transform('debowerify');
  return b;
}

function buildScripts(bundleable){
  return bundleable.bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    //.pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    //.pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    //.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(FRONTEND_PUBLIC_DIR));
}

gulp.task('scripts-watchified', function () { // reloadable bundling, , that's what takes 3s for every reload
  var bundleable = scriptsBundle(true);
  var build = _.partial(buildScripts, bundleable);
  bundleable.on('update', function (e) {
    console.log("Bundle update", e);
    return build();
  });
  bundleable.on('log', gutil.log);
  //bundleable.on('update', browserSync.reload);

  return build();
});
```

Comment: show us the `browserify` / `watchify` commands you are using.

Comment: not using commands, using them in gulp

Comment: ah ok..... did i understand you correctly... first you bundle your app with `watchify`. Then when you change something and watchify runs again (automatically) the bundle will be larger than before? :O

Comment: @marcel: no, the bundle does not get bigger, it just is very big in the first place; much more than when I didn't use `browserify` to structure my code, whereas the librairies are the same.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to to use factor-bundle ? https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle

Comment: @elad.chen: is factor-bundle relevant if I bundle into only one script?

Comment: i think, that it isn't unusual. `browserify` takes all code (also from external libraries) und put it into one file. additionally there is a sourcemap, that can be very large too.

Comment: @ValentinWaeselynck As far as I know if modules foo & bar are "requiring"
module zoo; browserify will include "zoo" module twice in it's end result ( the "bundle"). 

This is why factor-bundle exists. Let me know if that helps, and I'll write it as an answer.

Comment: @marcel: theoretically, the only difference between my old and new version is that the same scripts (including external libraries) are bundled together instead of concatenated. While there must be some additional glue code added by browserify, that hardly explains why the output is 3x bigger.

Comment: @elad.chen: that seems crazy, but let me experiment with it and tell you if that solves it.

Comment: how many lines do the smaller bundle contain? browserify creates a scope for each file... so when you have to files with 5 lines the scope function could be 3 times larger... :D

Comment: @marcel: well, maybe 2 or 3, since it's minified

Comment: @marcel and elad.chen see my edit

Comment: Is Browserify slow in general, or just for your use case? I cannot tell from your problem description. How does Browserify compare to other solutions, such as Hugo? Hugo rebuilds very quickly when a source file changes, partially because it is written in Go/Golang, which is a compiled language.